# Unable to create Feed in feedburner

Tags: feedburner

We are unable to create a feed for our website http://www.eccouncil.org on *FeedBurner*.  It gives an error:

> The URL does not appear to reference a valid XML file. We encountered the following problem: Error on line 15: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference".

Please Help!

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the `www.eccouncil.org` as the URL in Feedburner. This won't work. You need to point Feedburner to your existing RSS Feed's URL. I saw your site and didn't find one. Maybe you're not generating one?

Comment: Scratch that comment, I did find it. It's at `/rss`.

Comment: this question was asked two years and it is no longer be reproducible. so it should be deleted.